# Convert c++ struct of byte arrays to c#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I have a small section of code in `c++` and I need to have the same in `C#`.  Here is the `c++` code:

```
struct Texel { unsigned char r, g, b, a; }; 
Texel mytexturedata[] = 
{
   {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF}, // green
   {0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF}, // yellow
   {0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF}, // red
};
```

How do you do this is `c#`?

Thanks!

Comment: `Texel[] mytexturedata = { new Texel() { r = 0x00, g=0xFF, b=0x00,a=0xFF} , .. };` with the change of  `class Texel {  byte r {get;set;} byte g {get;set;} byte b {get;set;} byte a {get;set;} }`. BTW, `unsigned char` corresponds to `byte` in C#, `char` is 16-bit wide (UTF-16).

Comment: I think that byte is a better type than unsigned char in c# . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your struct to a class.

```
public class Texel
{
    public byte r { get; set; }
    public byte g { get; set; }
    public byte b { get; set; }
    public byte a { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do your assignment like this.

```
Texel[] mytexturedata =
{
    new Texel() { r = 0x00, g = 0xFF, b = 0x00, a = 0xFF }, // Green
    new Texel() { r = 0xFF, g = 0xFF, b = 0x00, a = 0xFF }, // Yellow
    new Texel() { r = 0xFF, g = 0x00, b = 0x00, a = 0xFF }  // Red
};
```